# Create report using data from 3 excel sheets sheets in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer

I just want to create a report using few excel sheets as the input in pentaho. After creating the report need to send it through email and to be specific the email should be scheduled.

Comment: Yes, that is the standard use of Pentaho. What is your question about ?

Comment: Hi, i want joing 2 or more excel sheets and merge into a table and retrive data out of it to create reports which contain bar charts, pir charts and etc. I tried inputing two excel sheets and merging them in PDI, but that joins doesnt work properly

Comment: Give a 3 line per sheet example. Also specify if you want to use the BA-EE server, the BI-EE serve or want a PDI+Report Designer solution.